# jQuery select a child from parent of parent of parent

Tags: jquery

I have this custom menu I've just built:

```
<div class="select_input_wrap">
    <div class="select_input_wrap_left">
        <input class="select_input" type="text" id="search_topics" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
    </div>
    <div class="select_input_wrap_right"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="select_input_menu" id="search_topics_menu">
        <ul class="custom_select_menu">
            <li>Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3</li>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3</li>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3</li>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3</li>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When somebody clicks an `<li>`, I want to grab the text from inside it and place it inside the closest  field situated before the `<li>`. This is not the only menu on my page, hence using `$(this)`, otherwise it would be as easy as putting the `.text()` in to the input field of a certain class or id.

I have been trying stuff like this:

```
$('.custom_select_menu li').click(function() {
    //$(this).closest('.select_input').val($(this).text());
    //$(this).closest('.select_input_wrap').children('input').val($(this).text());
});
```

But I just can't get there. Please can somebody explain how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, but `children` only selects children of the selected element, not descendants, you can use `find` method instead.

```
$('.custom_select_menu li').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.select_input_wrap').find('input').val($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That need some explanations:

When you are clicking on your LI, the handler function is executed with the context of the LI.

So, $(this) refer to the jQuery object embedding your LI.

First:

```
$(this).closest('.select_input').val($(this).text());
```

will not work because your `.select_input` is not a part of ancestors  - in fact this a child of a sibling of the parent of parent of your li :). `closest()` only search on the full line of ancestor.

Secondly:

```
$(this).closest('.select_input_wrap').children('input').val($(this).text());
```

will not work either because the `children()` is only searching on first level deep of children, so you should use `find()` instead and that would be good - find search recursively at any deep level

That's why modifying a little your second try will work:

```
$(this).closest('.select_input_wrap').find('input').val($(this).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
$('.custom_select_menu li').click(function() {
    var field = $(this).parents('.select_input_wrap').find('.select_input');
    field.val($(this).text());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZKnQh/